# Why the following two graphs have the same flow polynomials and the same Tutte Polynomials.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, geometric-topology, computational-mathematics

Please consider the following two graphs

[image]

I am obtaining that the two graphs have the same flow polynomial given by

$$\left(\lambda -1\right) \left(\lambda -2\right) \left(\lambda -3\right) \left(\lambda^{5}-15 \lambda^{4}+95 \lambda^{3}-323 \lambda^{2}+602 \lambda -497\right)$$

From other side I am obtaining that the two graphs have the same Tutte polynomial given by

[image]

My question is: why these two graphs have the same flow polynomial and Tutte polynomial?

Comment: What's the context for this? Is it a homework problem? Is it a research project? Personal diversion?

Comment: Do you know how the Flow polynomial is computed ? What do you know about its relation to Tutte polynomial ?

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues :   With the substitutions : $x= 0$ and $y = 1-\lambda$, Tutte polynomial is reduced to Flow polynomial.

Comment: @JuanOspina so getting the same flow polynomial is a simple consequence of having the same Tutte polynomial. Now, why would these graphs have the same Tutte polynomial ?

Answer (score 2):

The two graphs are isomorphic;  for such reason they have the same Tutte polynomial;  and then,  the same flow polynomial.

The adjacency matrix for the first graph is given by

$$ \left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}\right]$$

The adjacency matrix for the second graph is given by

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}\right]$$

The difference between the two adjancency matrices is given by

$$ \left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}\right]$$

The last matrix can be reduced to the null matrix using the following permutation over  the nodes of the second graph:

$[1 = 8, 2 = 12, 3 = 9, 4 = 13, 5 = 10, 6 = 14, 7 = 11, 8 = 1, 9 = 5, 10 = 2, 11 = 6, 12 = 3, 13 = 7, 14 = 4]$

As a result of the permutation,  the two adjacency matrices will be the same.

Given that the adjacency matrices of the two graphs are the same, then these two graphs are isomorphic.

Comment: Should explain how we can know they are isomorphic (e.g. exhibit an example of one).

Comment: An example using adjacency matrices was added in the answer.

Comment: You didn't specify a permutation, which means no example of an isomorphism was added. While I recognize adding the matrices took a lot of writing, I'm not sure what someone is supposed to get out of staring at a wall of numbers. (Plus, we should be clear we're talking about permuting nodes for one adjacency matrix, not both simultaneously. Not sure why you're mentioning the difference between the matrices.) Do you want to suggest feeding the matrices to a computer program?

Comment: Even if software spits out an isomorphism, I still wouldn't consider that an explanation, which would be ideal. The graphs are constructed a certain way; an explanation to my mind would make use of this construction and perhaps even generalize. (The construction appears to be joining two cycle graphs along a certain vertex bijection.) Or else, maybe an answer could show there isn't an isomorphism in general and that this particular pair is a quirk?

Comment: @elemelons I will complete the example soon.  For awhile please observe  that the isomorphism is evident.

Answer (score 1):

The two graphs are indeed isomorphic as Juan said, I have another point of view maybe you'll like it more?
If you check the path of the polygon in the middle, it visits each vertices in the middle (each time).
For the first you have the path $p_1 =(8,10,12,14,9,11,13)$ and for the second the cycle $p_2 = (8,11,14,10,13,9,12)$ so if you consider the permutation $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_{14}$ verifying
$$
\sigma_{|\{8,\dots,14\}} = \begin{pmatrix} p_1 \\ p_2\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}  8&10&12&14&9&11&13 \\ 8&11&14&10&13&9&12\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}  8&9&10&11&12&13&14 \\ 8&13&11&9&14&12&10\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}  8&13&11&9&14&12&10\end{pmatrix}$$

You then just need to ensure that each vertices in the middle is connected to the right vercite on the exterior.

You had for the first graph $1-8, 9-2, \dots$, but since we change the order, e.g. $9$ goes to $13$, we have to ensure the $2$ moves to $6$. So define
$$\sigma_{|\{1,\dots,7\}} = (n \mapsto n-7) \circ \sigma_{|\{8,\dots,14\}} \circ (n \mapsto n+7)$$.

Your $\sigma$ induces an iso on your graphs. And you have the matrix of $\sigma$ in $GL_n (Z)$ that is exactly the matrix of your iso

Comment: Many thanks. Your solution is wonderful.

Comment: It's a pleasure (beware it may have some small mistakes) the general idea is that when you have big matrices, it is easy for a computer to use it, but with your own head, it is better to have a drawing :) then see corresponding patterns between the vertices and edges.

Comment: Now I am seeing that the isomorphism is obvious. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, it is mainly because $2 \cdot 4 = 1$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ (or at least I believe).

Comment: Please look the following paper : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X07010837?via%3Dihub

Comment: Wow! This is nice, I must send it to my friend who is an absolute graph theory lover?

Comment: According with such paper: the isomorphism is due to 2*4=1 mod 7 (as you said), 2 + 5= 0 mod 7 and 3 + 4 =0  mod 7.